# python pd.to_excel keep scientific notation format

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which some columns contain numbers. My request is to keep the scientific notation. I am using :

```
f = final.style.format({
                    'a': "{:.3E}",
                    'b': "{:.3E}",
                    'c': "{:.3E}" }
            )
```

when I use `print()`, it shows the correct format which shows scientific notation.
when I use pd.to_excel my excel output keeps the decimals.

### How should I keep the scientific notation in excel output?

And I input excel have a column that contains both scientific notation and text. when I read the excel the pandas changed the scientific notation to decimals automatically when I convert to scientific notation the text changed to `NAN`. If I use `pd.to_numeric(final['total'], errors='ignore')`. the data type is still `'Object'`. Then I cannot change back to scientific notation.

### Is there any way I can keep the text and scientific notation?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you set the `float_format`  [parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) accordingly?

Comment: There are only some of the columns that need to be scientific notation. Others need to keep the same. What should I do?